# Read XML file tags one by one using Ant script

Tags: xml, ant

Please see attached XML file which i need to read in Ant script.

I am able to read xml tag values using xmlproperty as below

```
<xmlproperty file="pom.xml"/>
<echo>${project.dependencies.dependency.groupId}${line.separator}</echo>
<echo>${project.dependencies.dependency.artifactId}${line.separator}</echo>
<echo>${project.dependencies.dependency.version}${line.separator}</echo>
```

## I am getting output as below:

[echo] za.co.rmb.rti.common,za.co.rmb.rti.common

[echo] bw-library-security,bw-library-common-audit

[echo] ${project.dependencies.dependency.version}

## Please can you advise :

1) Why value of property project.dependencies.dependency.version is not being captured in output ?

2) I want separate output for each tag, like , 
 All Values for 1st dependency tag and Then values for second dependency tags.

## Expected Output:

za.co.rmb.rti.common

bw-library-common-audit

4.0.0

Once i get values in first dependency tag as above , i will save each of these these in separate  property and take some action like echoing in file.

Then it should give me values in second dependency tag as below which i will again capture and do some action

za.co.rmb.rti.common

bw-library-security

2.0.0

Comment: Sorry i forgot to attach XML file...How i can attach XML file now ? I don't see any buttons to edit my question and attach XML file.Here is XML tags

Comment: <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>za.co.rmb.rti.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>bw-library-common-audit</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <type>projlib</type>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>za.co.rmb.rti.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>bw-library-security</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <type>projlib</type>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>